# When are “to + verb” and “verb+ing” not interchangeable?

Tags: american-english, infinitive-vs-gerund

Like in the following example:

> I would really appreciate having some feedback on this topic.

Why can’t I just write “to have” instead of “having”?
In this case, they are not supposed to be interchangeable, but why?

Comment: From [Gerunds and Infinitives](https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/verbs-followed-by-gerunds-and-infinitives/): *There are certain verbs that can only be followed by one or the other, and **these verbs must be memorized.** Many of these verbs are listed below...* That webpage certainly looks like a useful resource to me.

Comment: If you really want to use *have* instead, you could say *I would really appreciate it **if I could have** some feedback on this topic.* (Thereby having it follow a different verb.) Note, however, that you can also simply dispense with *to have* altogether: *I would really appreciate some feedback on this topic.* The last is the more idiomatic of the possible constructions.

Comment: There is some general high theory on the question you have interest in. Though, it is complex and cumbersome, having a lot of special cases and exceptions. The rule of thumb here is that the word combination 'having some feedback on this topic' is a gerund phrase. It functions grammatically as a noun in a sentence. A noun identifies something that could exist before the moment of speaking in such a case, what is not possible for any infinitive in such pattern. The verb 'appreciate' means 'to be grateful' for something that already existed before the moment of speaking.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that, as the EngVid page on [Gerunds and Infinitives](https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/verbs-followed-by-gerunds-and-infinitives/) listed by  FumbleFingers says, this is simply an arbitrary rule of usage.

I disagree with a few of the statements on the page. but I agree with its general point nd with most of the specific classifications given there, and i can't advance any systematic criterion for which verbs take an infinitive, which take a gerund, and which can take either. Perhaps there is something in the history of the words or their earlier forms which would make a pattern here.

On specific verbs, the page lists "abhor" as requiring a gerund ("He abhors playing soccer.") but I think it can also, albeit less commonly take an infinitive ("He abhors to use the passive voice.")

"Appear" in the sense "seem to" takes an infinitive "This appears to be a rule without a reason.") but in the sense of "shows up" or "becomes visible" can take a gerund. ("At the start of the show, she appears playing a saxophone in a green costume." "In *Hamlet* the ghost appears walking the battlements of the castle.")

"Chance" is listed as taking an infinitive, but such a sentence as "I can't chance leaving the problem unsolved." seems perfectly natural to me.

Other disputes over the exact rule for a given verb might be made, but the basic fact is that the rule is specific for each individual verb.